# Creating Grid on my Image

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am currently trying to create a moving character in a Map using AWT and Swings.
I need help on trying to create a `GridLayout` on my Image. I have tried using `setLayout(new GridLayout())` and it just doesn't work.
If possible, I would also like to incorporate a `KeyListener` to this.

Currently, Here's my Code for the Image:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{

    GUI(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon("path-to-backgroundImage");
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(image1);
        add(label1);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.pack();
        gui.setTitle("Map");
    }
}
```

And Here's the GridLayout I had with the code, but it doesn't work:

```
  setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));
  for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(cellIcon);
        add(label);
     }
  }
```

Help is always highly appreciated!

Comment: *"but it Doesn't work"* in what way doesn't it work?

Comment: label not showing on the map.

Comment: This could be an issue with the `ImageIcon`, try setting the labels text to something

Comment: instead of setLayout(new FlowLayout()) its setLayout(new GridLayout())

Answer (score 0):

```
JLabel label1 = new JLabel(image1);
add(label1);
```

You add the label to the frame, which is reasonable:

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
      JLabel label = new JLabel(cellIcon);
      add(label);
   }
}
```

But then you change the layout of the frame and add more labels to the frame. Your code doesn't make sense. If you want to add the grid of labels to the background image then the code should be:

```
label1.setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
      JLabel label = new JLabel(cellIcon);
      label1.add(label);
   }
}
```

If you need more help then poste a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. The random lines of code don't tell us the context of how the code is used.